# Google colab deep learning python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am interested in trying out GPU deep learning with Google colab and I a following this tutorial blog to setup the deep learning environment with a Google drive:
https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d

I have setup the Google drive and appropriate folder directories, and I am to the point in the blog "***Running or Importing .py Files with Google Colab
Run these codes first in order to install the necessary libraries and perform authorization***" And then I am supposed to run this code in the Google Ipython editor:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

The code executes as its supposed too and then a hyperlink & box appears where I a can copy and paste an authorization key. When I paste in the key nothing happens. The icon if Python is busy just spins and spins (busy) forever... Hitting enter appears to remove the authorization key and I dont think that is appropriate either.

Restarting the virtual machine doesnt appear to do anything either with a `!kill -9 -1` and then rerunning the code... Any tips help thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter after entering the code should be sufficient. What is the problem you encounter? (After you enter the code, you'll need to execute additional code to access Drive as described in the linked article.)

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Comment: Well I started out the day today with the same Google IPython notebook as yesterday. 1st `!kill -9 -1` to reboot/reset the virtual machine which works fine. Then the process as above in the original post, re-running the code (which works) and then the hyperlink pops up to retrieve the activation code. I pasted it into the box and pressed ENTER like you said to do...but now even a good hour+ later its still working (busy)...Any ideas what I am doing wrong?? Thank you

Comment: What browser are you using? Is there an error on the Javascript console? Does this issue occur in an incognito window?

Comment: Im using Google Chrome and it says that it is up to date. Version 68.0.3440.106.. I did another `!kill -9 -1` which goes quick - seems to work... In Chrome in developer tools (not  much knowledge here) there does appear to be errors in the console... external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180809_085320-RC00_208056038:2793 Ignoring benign restart error: CustomError: Runtime died at: 
 Error
    at q0 (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180809_085320-RC00_208056038:2741:383)

Comment: Not alot of knowledge here.. But I see a few 504's & 400's: external.js?vrz=colab_20180809_085320-RC00_208056038:1281 POST https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/m-2uwsfznpn9wd1/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MKbVEjO&sid=NrVf0rhHlYVSfvlBAAAA 504 ()

Comment: external.js?vrz=colab_20180809_085320-RC00_208056038:1281 POST https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/m-2uwsfznpn9wd1/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MKbVTQA&sid=NrVf0rhHlYVSfvlBAAAA 400 ()

Comment: I'd recommend opening a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/). StackOverflow isn't going to work for back-and-forth diagnosis.